# how to compare two list and count the number of one list between another list's object

Tags: python, list, count, compare

if I have two list
one named "base" and is used to breakdown another list
another is "match"
like below

```
base = [4,7,13,14,19]
match = [1,2,5,9,10,12,15,18]
```

i  want to count how many numbers of "match" are within two objects of "base", and store in another list, called "result"
So the "result" should be [1,3,0,2]

I used this way

```
fianl_num = [] 
m = 0
countnum = 0
for j in match:
    if j < base[m]:
        countnum += 1
    else:
        m = m+1
        fianl_num.append(countnum)
        countnum = 0
print(fianl_num)`
```

However, there is a problem, if the match's object is bigger than base's object, the current match's object will be considered else and move on to compare next match's object to the next base's object. As a result, the current base's object is skip

for my example/base = [4,7,13,14,19]/match = [1,2,5,9,10,12,15,18]
my code results in [2,0,2,0]
because 5 is bigger than 4, so it moves on to compare 9 to 7, skip the process comparing 5 to 7

Comment: What do you mean with *within two objects of `base`*?

Comment: Didn't get on how did u get 1,3,0,2 in the first case

Comment: To be more specific, can you explain how result is equal to [1,3,0,2]? Maybe, you can write it down step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sum()` to determine the number of elements in `match` between `i` and `i+1` elements of `base`.

```
for i in range(len(base)-1):
    count=sum(base[i]<x<base[i+1]for x in match)
    l.append(count)
```

Output:

```
[1,3,0,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be better ways for this. But 1 way can be like this:

```
base = [4,7,13,14,19]
match = [1,2,5,9,10,12,15,18]
l = []
i = 0
while i < len(base)-1:
    count = 0
    for a in match:
        if base[i] < a < base[i+1]:
            count += 1
    l.append(count)
    i += 1
print l
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 0, 2]
```

Comment: Who is downvoting? :D Please be generous to mention the reason as well :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
base = [4,7,13,14,19]
match = [1,2,5,9,10,12,15,18]

fianl_num = []
m = 0
len = len(match)
countnum = 0
for j in base:
    while m < len and match[m] < j:
        m = m+1
        countnum += 1
    if j > base[0]:
        fianl_num.append(countnum)
    countnum = 0
print(fianl_num)

#[1, 3, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the one line list comprehension is easier to understand than the problem description:

```
base = [4,7,13,14,19]
match = [1,2,5,9,10,12,15,18]

[sum(1 for e in match if lower < e < upper) for lower, upper in zip(base, base[1:])]

Out[7]: [1, 3, 0, 2]
```

can be a few char shorter if you are OK with the summing of bools (`True = 1`, `False = 0`)  as in Trelzevir's answer

```
[sum(lower < e < upper for e in match) for lower, upper in zip(base, base[1:])]
```

older python versions may need extra braces for sum's arg to be recognized as a generator